# Downloading Images With Python & Pillow Library

Tags: python, image, python-requests, python-imaging-library

I'm using Pillow & Requests to download a few thousand images from multiple websites. I have the URLs for the images and the formats are typically png or jpg.

I wrote the following code:

```
r = requests.get(IMAGE_URL, headers=self.headers)
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.content))
image.save(FILE_PATH)
```

This seems to work for some images and fail for other. The exception I get is the following:

OSError:

```
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at HEX_VALUE>
```

Comment: Do you have an actual URL that produces that result? I suspect the image that is served has an invalid format, or maybe is empty.

Comment: sure, take this one for [example](https://www.proplan.com/media/1949/dog_big_cans_savor_adult_beef_and_rice_entree_classic_detail_crop.png)

Comment: Well, your code fragment works OK with that URL, at least on my machine. I'm unable to reproduce the error. Could you try it on another machine? The exact and complete code I used can be found at http://motoom.net/arby.py

Comment: I noticed you left out the optional headers argument, turns out I was using the incorrect header constant in my code which was restricting the host...

Comment: So now it works, without the header? Nice! Why not paste your comment as the answer, maybe someone else in the future will benefit from it ;-)